# How can I get notified when someone subscribes to my site on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I have a website and I want user to subscribe to get informed about the site but I want their emails to be sended to my mail how can i do this help please thanks

Comment: What are you using to manage your users? Have you tried and think of something? Google maybe? have you searched for some way of registering users and sending emails with Rails? Do you have a code snippet to show us what you have right now? ... If you want some help consider helping us understand you first!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a contact model, you could then add an on_create filter that notifies you by email.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is a cron job. [Clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) is a nice gem that helps you create one.

Answer (score 0):

You can send email to admin using on_create method in user model.

like after_create :subscribe_to_newsletter
def subscribe_to_newsletter
  code goes here
end